# Reloading parent window on closing colorBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, colorbox

Sorry for my little knowledge of java-script.I have an application where sign-up form is opening in a color box and successfull registration we are showing a welcome message on another color box.

i need to do reload the parent page when user close any of the color box but not sure how to do this.
the js and HTML being provided by third party so can not change there file,after looking in there code i found the following code

```
function inlineLightbox(h) {
    jQuery.colorbox({
        opacity: 0.6,
        inline: true,
        href: h,
        onOpen: function() {
            jQuery('#colorbox').addClass('inline');
        },
        onComplete: function() {
            jQuery('#colorbox a.close, #colorbox a.btn-close').click(function() {
                jQuery.colorbox.close();


    jQuery('#product-popup-help').removeClass('active'); jQuery('#product-editors-notes').addClass('active');
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

where `h` is the `id` of the `div` whose data need to be shown the overlay.Is there any way to write code in my own HTML file so that when user close those  overlay, i can capture the close even and can reload parent window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
    location.reload();
});
```